# Czmq memory leakage in a simple PUB / SUB application

Tags: c, zeromq, publish, subscribe

I am facing a memory leakage issue while using czmq library for a simple **`PUB / SUB`** application. So, here is the description:

The setup contains multiple publishers and multiple subscribers. Each publisher and subscriber is a separate thread. Threads are normal POSIX threads on a Linux machine. I am sending messages from the publisher to subscriber using `zmsg_send` and `zframe`. Each message containing one frame each. I am able to send and receive messages, but over time I am seeing memory occupied by the application increases. I am using tcp pub-sub sockets.

One thing I would like to mention is that after sending the message I am not destroying it as it is mentioned in the documentation that it will.destroy them after sending successfully. While receiving the message I copy the received message into a local structure and then I destroy the frame and zmsg. I am using zpoller to wait on the socket for messages. It's running on an arm processor. Could anyone please guide me towards, what things I need to keep in mind to avoid the memory leakage? The Application sends messages at the rate of 10 Hz.

And clue on the general mistakes that I might be making will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: After your being Member for 4 years, 7 months, where is your MCVE-code and why you did not reward previous help and answer provided?

Comment: I am sorry. I haven't asked many questions. I have accepted the answers and upvoted them when I found them correct. I am about to put the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dig further to work out what is leaking the memory.

Run your application under `valgrind`, once you are at the point you think the memory is being leaked, break the execution and `valgrind` should report all possible leaks. Hopefully the real leak should stand out as it will be large and obvious.

Other things to try would be reducing the **`HWM`**'s to 1 for all sockets and see if that makes a difference. It could be that the memory leak is just ZeroMQ using the buffers (set by `HWM`). Linux will not always return the memory to the heap if its freed unless it is needed elsewhere.

Finally thanks to ZeroMQ's architecture you could very easily split your application into two, then your `PUB` and `SUB` would be separate and narrow down the leak further.